# Proof Confusions: How do I approach this?

Tags: proof-writing, quadratics

***Prove:*** $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n > y \implies (\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}, 0 \leq \epsilon < 1 \land y = (n+\epsilon)^2 - n^2)$

What do I do? The thing that confuses me the most is why is $y$ given as arbitrary and why do we have to show that it's equal to something. Wouldn't that mean $y$ isn't arbitary?
How do I approach this proof?

Comment: Please work first, in your question, to translate into words, what you are to prove.

Comment: for all reals y, and for all positive integers n, if n > y then y must be equal to (n+e)^2 - n^2.

Comment: And what is $\varepsilon$ ? Is it for all $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: for some e, not all

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>y$. We want to show the existence of $\varepsilon\in[0,1[$ such that $y=(n+\varepsilon)^2-n^2$. Let $f(\varepsilon)=(n+\varepsilon)^2-n^2$ for all $\varepsilon\in[0,1[$. $f$ is a continuous non-decreasing function, thus by the intermediate value theorem, $f([0,1[)=[f(0),f(1)[=[0,(n+1)^2-n^2[=[0,2n+1[$. But $n>y$ so $2n+1>y$ and thus $y\in[0,2n+1[$ and because of what said above, there exists $\varepsilon\in[0,1[$ such that $y=f(\varepsilon)=(n+\varepsilon)^2-n^2$.

Comment: Without IVT, what would you do? Is it possible to give a well-defined value for epsilon or just say it exists?

Comment: You can directly take $\varepsilon=\sqrt{y+n^2}-n$ and verify that $\varepsilon\in[0,1[$

Answer (score 0):

Solve $y=(n+\varepsilon)^{2}-n^{2}$ for $\varepsilon$, the equation has two roots $\varepsilon_1= \sqrt{y+n^{2}}-n$ and $\varepsilon_2=-\sqrt{y+n^{2}}-n$. Then prove that
 $0\leq\varepsilon_1<1$ or $0\leq\varepsilon_2<1$. Is easy to show that $\varepsilon_2\leq0$ and for $\varepsilon_1$ note that $$0\leq y<n<2n+1\Rightarrow 0\leq y<2n+1$$ sum $n^{2}$  $$n^{2}\leq y+n^{2}<n^{2}+2n+1\Rightarrow n^{2}\leq y+n^{2}<(n+1)^{2}$$ take square root $$n\leq \sqrt{y+n^{2}}<(n+1)\Rightarrow 0\leq \sqrt{y+n^{2}}-n<1\Rightarrow0\leq\varepsilon_1<1$$.

Comment: When you take square root, why is $\sqrt{n^2} = n$ and not $|n|$? Is it true that $|n| \leq \sqrt{y + n^2} < |n+1| \implies n \leq \sqrt{y+n^2} < n+1$?

Comment: $n$  is a positive integer then $\vert n\vert=n$